# Touchpad stops working after waking up

Tags: touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and when I suspend my laptop and then open the lid, to wake it, my touchpad isn't working anymore.
Can anyone help me with this? My keyboard is working fine, but my touchpad isn't.

I use an Inspiron 3542

Comment: Can you switch to Ubuntu using xorg (instead of wayland) and confirm that this is still a problem?